# TOAD- PL/sql script output to datagrid

Tags: plsql

Is there a way to output the pl/sql script to datagrid directly? I have a pl/sql script which outputs to console using dbms_output.putline(). I am trying to execute this with TOAD and would like to know if there is any option available to re-route the output to daragrid besides printing it to the console.

Thanks,
Jasu

Comment: Probably, no.  But results can be firstly stored by PL/SQL block to a collection inside a package, and then selected from the collection by following `select from table(your_collection)` into datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, no. But you can use one of the following solution :

1. Use a temporary table and then select on the table.
2. Use a collection and then select on the collection.